# I cannot raise ens34 on ubuntu 16.04 server vm[Failed to start raise network interfaces]

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, network-manager, vmware

1. I installed vmware fusion on my PC, and installed ubuntu 16.04 server vm through vmware
2. Then I added another Nic through vmware
3. When I boot the vm, I can only saw one dhcp Nic ens33(eth0), so I configured the other Nic ens34(eth1)
   [Figure 1: How I edit file /et/network/interfaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCRCr.png)
4. Then I restart network service through `systemctl restart networking`, but I got an error and when I run `systemctl status networking` it shows:
   [Figure 2: Error Failed to start raise network interfaces.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUabq.png)

pls help me solve this issue, thanks a lot ... lot ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem and the solution was changing the names of the interfaces to the usual values eth0, eth1...

http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/mini-howtos/change-default-network-name-ens33-to-old-eth0-on-ubuntu-16-04.html

In my case, eth0 is configured with dhcp and eth1 static without gateway, in order to force ubuntu to gety internet through eth0.

Hope it serve